# Error - build method compilation Error at ReceiveBuilder, type scala.Product cannot be resolved

Tags: java, akka, akka-actor

I am new to Akka-Actor.

Trying to run simple akka-actor program to understand akka-actor.

I am not able to resolve two compilation errors.

```
The method build() from the type AbstractPFBuilder<Object,BoxedUnit> refers to the missing type PartialFunction
```

**AND**

```
The type scala.Product cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files. 

Compilation error at Props props() method.
```

The below one is actual code.

**AkkaActor Program:**

```
package com.abcplusd.akka;

import akka.actor.AbstractLoggingActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.japi.pf.ReceiveBuilder;

    public class AkkaStarted {

      static class Counter extends AbstractLoggingActor {
        static class Message {}
        private int count = 0;

        {
          receive(ReceiveBuilder
              .match(Message.class, this::onMessage)
              .build()
              );
        }

        private void onMessage(Message message) {
          count ++;
          System.out.println("Increased Counter: " + count);
        }
        public static Props props() {
          return Props.create(Counter.class);
        }

       }
      public static void main (String[] args) {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("Sample1");
        final ActorRef counter =  system.actorOf(Counter.props(), "Counter");
        counter.tell(new Counter.Message(), ActorRef.noSender());
        System.out.println("Enter to Terminate");
      }

    }
```

AkkaActor version 2.4.9.

Below my pom.xml settings.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <akka.version>2.4.9</akka.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the compilation issues by changing scala-lang version.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>
```